# Why can't I use a compound assignment to set multiple variables to null?

Tags: java

It's well-known that you can write

```
int a;
int b;
b = a = 3;
```

But I'd like to write

```
foo f;
bar b;    
f = b = null;
```

This is not syntatically valid. Presumably because `null` has a type associated with it when assigned to `b` and that type cannot be assigned to `f` even if the value of the reference is `null`. Is this correct and is there an alternative, other than the obvious `f = null; b = null;` ?

Comment: `Presumably because null has a type associated with it when assigned to b and that type cannot be assigned to f even if the value of the reference is null` Not exactly. The reason behind it is that you are trying to assign `b` to `f`, but `b` is not the same type of `f`. It's like saying `banana = potato`, but they are two completely different kinds of fruit.

Answer (score 5):

Your two snippets are not exactly analogs. A better analog would be:

```
int a;
double b;
a = b = 3;  // error
```

which produces the same error. It's the fact that the types of `f` and `b` are different that causes the problem, not the fact that we're assigning `null`. Specifically, the type of `(b = null)` is `bar`, which is not assignment-comparable with a `foo`.

You're likely better off performing separate assignments.

Answer (score 3):

You get an error here because `f` and `b` belong to different types (`foo` and `bar` respectively) and you can't assign `b` to `f`.

```
foo f;
foo b;
f = b = null;
```

should work

Comment: Simple and correct +1. Though I wonder if you can cast the assignment like `f = ((foo) b = null)`. Of course not advisable at all, but *possible*

Comment: @Rogue Only if it's a legal cast (e.g. foo extends bar).

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct, you can't chain the assignments like that because a `Foo` is not a `Bar`. However, this is even shorter then your example.

```
Foo f = null;
Bar b = null;
```